# Why Discount Promotional Offer in Distriqt ANE for iOS not working in Production mode?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3

We are Distriqt's InAppBilling ANE for normal purchase and for Promotional Discount Purchase.

- When we purchased Discount Offer in Sandbox for the user who has previously purchased a subscription it works perfectly.
- When we tried purchasing Discount in Live Production, for an active subscriber who has switched off their auto-renewal from iTunes settings, the **subscription did not complete**.

To know whether the user has turned off auto-renewal, we have used `notification_type` and `auto_renew_status` of server notification.
In production, we get a popup specifying the price of the discount and the price after the discount period ends. After that, the subscription does not complete. There are no more popups.
How do we make it work in Production?

```
Environment:
AIR SDK version: AIR SDK 32.0.0.116
Device OS: iOS 12.3
Device version: iPad Pro
Development IDE: Flash CC
Development OS: iOS
```

Comment: As a guess I'd say the signature you are generating and passing to the purchase isn't correct in the live environment. Could you post some code demonstrating what you are doing?

Comment: I am getting following logs in Live Production mode :  dispatch: purchases:queue:removed data: {"purchases":[{"transactionIdentifier":"EAA27D01-9EFB-4A2A-9934-F208096C7CD0","quantity":1,"errorCode":"0","transactionState":"transaction:failed","productId":"com.abc.xyz","signature":"","developerPayload":"","transactionDate":0,"originalMessage":"","error":"Cannot connect to iTunes Store"}]}